# Always display data labels above columns in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

How can I set the HighCharts options to ensure that column graphs are always rendered where the data label is always on top of the column? Attached is an example where one of my labels is forced below.

I've tried many combination in dataLabels with no luck:

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    }
```

JSFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NKXRk/)

[image: HighCharts Example]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to disable crop and overflow, see: http://jsfiddle.net/NKXRk/4/

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                crop: false,
                overflow: 'none'
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also increase [maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding) parameter http://jsfiddle.net/NKXRk/3/

```
maxPadding:0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be easier:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    inside: false,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the data labels in your series call:

```
series:[{
name:"Odometer",
data:[{"y":94.98},{"y":182.96},{"y":160.97},{"y":18.00},{"y":117.97},{"y":6.00},{"y":127.97}],
dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: '1',
            align: 'center',
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            rotation: 0,
}
```

}]

http://jsfiddle.net/NKXRk/1/

Then if your labels still overlap the columns a bit (column 2 in fiddle above), set your yAxis max a bit higher:

```
yAxis:{ max: 250 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NKXRk/2/

Answer (score 2):

The crop&overflow/maxPadding options didn't work for me, this is what did the job for me to align it properly:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            y: -20,
            verticalAlign: 'top'
        }
     }
}
```